# sequelize create new record with already existing foreign key

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to create a new login record for the existing user. 
My User model is like this:

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {  });
  User.associate = function(models) {
    models.User.hasMany(models.Login, {
      foreignKey: 'userId',
      as: 'loginUserId'
    });
  };
  return User;
};
```

My Login model looks like this:

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Login = sequelize.define('Login', {
    loginId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    ipAddress: DataTypes.STRING,
    isSuccessfullLogin: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
  }, {});
  Login.associate = function(models) {
    Login.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'userId',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      as: 'loginUserId'
    });
  };
  return Login;
};
```

When I try to insert a record in the Login table through this code:

```js
const loginRecord = await models.Login.create({
    ipAddress: "127.0.0.1,
    isSuccessfullLogin: true,
    loginUserId: 2,
  })
```

It throws me the error

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Field 'loginUserId' doesn't have a default value

Note: Mysql shows me the loginUserId in the Login table and it also shows me the constraint of it as the foreign key.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding filed **id** to model **Login** and change **id** to primaryKey

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Login = sequelize.define('Login', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    ipAddress: DataTypes.STRING,
    isSuccessfullLogin: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
  }, {});
  Login.associate = function(models) {
    Login.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'userId',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      as: 'loginUserId'
    });
  };
  return Login;
};
```

Insert record to table Login:

```
const loginRecord = await models.Login.create({
    ipAddress: "127.0.0.1,
    isSuccessfullLogin: true,
    userId: 2,
  })
```